# Having trouble uploading image from Angular 8 to ASP.Netcore Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have spent the whole day trying to get this to work, I have looked at the following:

- https://www.talkingdotnet.com/upload-file-angular-5-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api/
- https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/

and many more than I can count.

All I want is to send an a form and an image. The errors am getting are:

- Missing content-type boundary
- Incorrect Content-Type
- The function evaluation requires all threads to run

In angular

```
register(user: UserViewModel, logo: File) {
    // We use formData because we can't send file as an object
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("user", JSON.stringify(user));

    formData.append("logo", logo);

    console.log(formData);

    return this.http.post<UserRegisterViewModel>(`${UserAPI.API_User}/${"register"}`, formData).pipe(map(user => {

      return user;

    }));
  }
```

Than my c# code looks like so

```cs
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("register")]
        //[Consumes("application/json", "multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAsync()
        {

            IFormFile logo = null;

            try
            {

                // Get the logo
                logo = Request.Form.Files[0];
                // Get the user json string
                var userJson = Request.Form["user"];
```

Comment: Why are people down voting this, if you have a solution post it, I have tried others and they don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it, I had a break point on

```
logo = Request.Form.Files[0];
```

For some reason there is a bug in VS2017 and 2019.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/146887/vs2017-v4-requestform-debug.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the file from `Request.Form` . you can follow below code sample :

Client side :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/upload', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
.subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
    this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    this.message = 'Upload success.';
    this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
    }
});
```

Server side :

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        var folderName = Path.Combine("StaticFiles", "Images");
        var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

       .....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Or you can get file with FromForm:

Client side :

```
let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

this.http.post('YourURL', formData, {headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',     
  'Content-Disposition' : 'multipart/form-data'
},reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
  .subscribe(event => {
    ....
  });
```

Then server side will be :

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
{


}
```